# Using inner joins gives too many results

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with INNER JOINs. I'm assuming I'm making some critical, yet basic error in my theory.

Table structure:

- BookDB - this table includes data about the books in our library (title, barcode, check out status, etc)
- LibraryDB - this table includes data about who checked out what book when
- StudentDB - this table includes data about students (name, id number, etc)

I made a page which listed all the books currently checked out by using the check out status of the BookDB table. But of course this doesn't let me know who has it.

In order to also display who has checked out the book, I want to call the LibraryDB, which records who checked it out, then call the StudentDB, which contains the name, etc of the student.

So I made a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM BookDB 
INNER JOIN LibraryDB ON BookDB.barcode = LibraryDB.barcode
INNER JOIN StudentDB ON LibraryDB.studentid = StudentDB.studentid
WHERE BookDB.status = '$checkinstatus' 
ORDER BY title ASC
```

The problem is that instead of just getting the result of the person who checked it out most recently, I get every person who ever checked it out.

I realize this is probably simple but I've tried looking at other similar posts and can't seem to figure out the basic problem here. I realize I need to restrict the query somehow, but don't know the syntax for doing it the way I want to.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My current output looks like this:

```
Animals in danger   A1  Shingen Tomita  9780194233798   Edit Book   Delete Book
Armans journey  A1  Ayaka Morikawa  9780521184939   Edit Book   Delete Book
Armans journey  A1  Ayaka Morikawa  9780521184939   Edit Book   Delete Book
Armans journey  A1  Naomi Maki  9780521184939   Edit Book   Delete Book
Armans journey  A1  Naomi Maki  9780521184939   Edit Book   Delete Book
Armans journey  A1  Iwamoto Kazumi  9780521184939   Edit Book   Delete Book
Armans journey  A1  Iwamoto Kazumi  9780521184939   Edit Book   Delete Book
Armans journey  A1  Kanata Shokai   9780521184939   Edit Book   Delete Book
Bens big swim   OD1 Keiichiro Takemura  9780194722674   Edit Book   Delete Book
Bens big swim   OD1 Keiichiro Takemura  9780194722674   Edit Book   Delete Book
Bens big swim   OD1 Takato Suzuki   9780194722674   Edit Book   Delete Book
```

For all the same books, I'd like to output just the last entry for each unique book:

```
Animals in danger   A1  Shingen Tomita  9780194233798   Edit Book   Delete Book
Armans journey  A1  Kanata Shokai   9780521184939   Edit Book   Delete Book
Bens big swim   OD1 Takato Suzuki   9780194722674   Edit Book   Delete Book
```

Comment: You could try `ORDER BY LibraryDB.date DESC LIMIT 1` to get the most recent book for the given `$checkinstatus`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This gives me the most recent book for the checkin status, but I'd like to get the most recent status for each individual book. I put the example in my original post.

Comment: Can you provide your schema and insert statement of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't puzzle out what to do, so I just went and added a column to the BookDB showing who the most recent check-outer was, which eliminated the need to call the LibraryDB records table, and therefore took care of the problem of getting every past record and not just the most recent one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way :

```
SELECT * FROM BookDB,LibraryDB,StudentDB WHERE BookDB.barcode = LibraryDB.barcode AND LibraryDB.studentid = StudentDB.studentid AND  BookDB.status = '$checkinstatus' ORDER BY title ASC;
```

Comment: This returns the same result as the query I posted.